# How to create sitemap.xml & Where I place that on my react JS website

Tags: reactjs, seo

I am confused about the sitemap file implementation. I have sitemap file with configuration where i place and how to run & check

1.Public folder: [image]

2.src folder[image]

3.sitemapinstance.js

[image]

Where I create sitemap.xml file. I was created on source folder is this correct way. any can help me for solve this issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap-generator
This package has the option to generate a sitemap as well.